# How to sort the array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to sort an array of objects in javascript. Below is the example data.

```
const example = [
    {
        name: "c_name",
        children: [{
            name: "child",
            email: "child1@dev.com",
            children: [{
                name: "nested_child",
                email: "nestedchild1@dev.com",
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "a_name",
        children: [{
            name: "some_name",
            email: "some_name@dev.com",
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "name",
        children: [{
            name: "child_name",
            email: "child_name@dev.com",
            children: []
        }]
    }
];
```

Should sort this array based on property 'name' and the children object should be sorted again based on 'name' property.

So the expected output is like below, and would like to retain other properties as well like email property in children.

a_name
     some_name
  c_name
     child
     nested_child
   name
      child_name

What i have done...i have a sort function that sorts the array by name property. however dont know how to sort the children object with name property.

const sorted_example = example.sort(this.sort_by_name());

```
sort_by_name = () => {
return (a, b) => {
    let result;
    const a_value = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const b_value = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (a_value > b_value) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (a_value < b_value) {
        result = -1;
    } else {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
};
```

};

Could someone help me how to continue with this. thanks.

Comment: How can you sort children? In your example the children property is an object and can only have one name property.

Comment: edited the data.

Comment: So you would like to recursively sort children if there are children? The name property is unique within every array?

Comment: yes...name property is unique and recursively sort children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers got you there most of the way but you need to sort again if an item has children. In my example I don't mutate the original array (use `.slice` to make a shallow copy so `.sort` doesn't mutate).

```js
const example = [{"name":"c_name","children":[{"name":"child","email":"child1@dev.com","children":[{"name":"nested_child","email":"nestedchild1@dev.com"}]},{"name":"b"},{"name":"a"}]},{"name":"a_name","children":[{"name":"some_name","email":"some_name@dev.com","children":[]}]},{"name":"name","children":[{"name":"child_name","email":"child_name@dev.com","children":[]}]}];

const sortRecursive = (data) => {
  const recur = (arr) =>
    arr
      .slice()
      .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
      //check each item to see if it has children that is an array
      .map(
        (item) =>
          //if item has children that is an array then sort that
          //  and it's childrens childrens children
          Array.isArray(item.children)
            ? {
                ...item,
                children: recur(item.children),
              }
            : item, //no children, just return the item
      );
  return recur(data);
};
//note that sortRecursive does not change example but returns a new array
//  that is sorted
console.log(sortRecursive(example));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your children are arrays instead of objects as per your example:

```
const example = [
        {
            name: "c_name",
            children: [{
                name: "child",
                email: "child1@dev.com",
                children: [{
                    name: "nested_child",
                    email: "nestedchild1@dev.com",
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            name: "a_name",
            children: [{
                name: "some_name",
                email: "some_name@dev.com",
                children: []
            }]
        },
        {
            name: "name",
            children: [{
                name: "child_name",
                email: "child_name@dev.com",
                children: []
            }]
        }
    ];
```

a quick way would be:

```
    example
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        .map(m => {
            return {
                name: m.name,
                children: m.children.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
            };
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i get an error cannot read sort of undefined at line.... children: m.children.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

Comment: some of your children arrays might be undefined (not there). Add a check like     children: m.children === undefined ? [] : m.children.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the sort() method

```
example.sort((el, q) => el.name.localeCompare(q.name))
```